# Does golang have any sorted container like Java SortedMap or c++ map/set or priority_set?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, go, set, containers

Does golang have any sorted container, so after I insert all the data, I iterate this container and get ordered result?

Thanks.

Comment: Not in the standard library!

Comment: You can use something like a sorted set that maintains order on insertion and update. This github.com/wangjia184/sortedset is something you can try

Comment: As part of golang 1.18 generics, the slices, maps & constraints package have been introduced which can be used to implement sorted containers. However, you still have to implement it yourself or use a third-party package. See https://github.com/zavitax/sortedset-go for example, which implements the aforementioned SortedSet with generics.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `container/heap` will help.
Here is the doc: https://pkg.go.dev/container/heap